# Commas with "ranged from a low of X .... to a high of X ... "

Tags: commas

Does there need to be commas after "day" in both instances? Would this be considered a contract situation for which I would need commas to separate, or is it a string of prepositional phrases that do not require commas?

... the period under review ranged from a low of $10 per day, to a high of $20 per day, with an average of $15 per day.

Comment: The commas might be considered to aid parsing. They are not 'necessary', but I'd certainly include at least the second.

Answer (score 1):

No comma at all, I would say. There is no parenthetical apposition that needs to be separated. PS. It should be "an average".